# SQL Server: JSON Auditing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build an auditing strategy using triggers.  I originally tried this:

[Trigger Based Change Data capture](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/trigger-based-change-data-capture)

It worked pretty well: it produced a nicely-formatted JSON, that looked like this:

```
{
    "columns" :[
     { 
        "name": "ID",
        "value:" : {
          "old": "1",
          "new": "2"
        }
     },
     {
        "name": "ModifiedOn",
        "value:" : {
          "old": "2020-02-14 16:00:00",
          "new": "2020-02-15 13:00:00"
        }
     } 
    ]
}
```

It even listed what columns were updated in the update trigger.  It worked well - until the system hit load.  Because the trigger selects info from system tables, it pretty much killed performance because of deadlocks.

I modified the script to include NOLOCK hints, but I'm also using a bulk upload library for EF Core; it uses temp tables, and technically 'modifies' the schema - so I was still running into deadlocks with sch-s and sch-m locks.

I modified the script to simply select the values in inserted/deleted into the audit tables but it's a lot harder to read.

The following (also found on SO) gets me close:

```
SELECT [name] = b.[key],
VALUE = CAST(b.[value] as NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM inserted i,
cross apply
(SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM INSERTED FOR JSON PATH,
     WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))) B
FOR JSON PATH
```

But it only grabs the values from the first row.

Has anyone done anything similar to this?
I could have the script generate the statements if I have to 'hard-code' the columns, if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: I struggle to see any reason to store this as JSON. If you just store it relationally you just use standard relational performance tricks like indexes. Is the performance issue writing to the log or reading back out of it?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm actually trying to insulate the auditing from schema changes.  The performance issue was that the original auditing script (in the link) was joining on system tables.  So, for example, if two or more rows were being inserted, I would get a deadlock.  

NOLOCKs helped, but I was still getting a schema lock.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @inserted table
(
id int primary key clustered,
colA int,
colB varchar(10),
colC uniqueidentifier,
colD date
)

insert into @inserted(id, ColA, colB, colC, colD)
values
(1, 100, 'ABC', newid(), getdate()),
(2, 200, 'DEF', newid(), getdate()),
(3, 300, 'KLM', newid(), getdate()),
(4, 400, 'XYZ', newid(), getdate());


select id, (select i.* for json path) as thejson
from @inserted as i;



declare @deleted table
(
id int primary key clustered,
colA int,
colB varchar(10),
colC uniqueidentifier,
colD date
)

insert into @deleted(id, ColA, colB, colC, colD)
values
(1, 100, 'ABC', newid(), getdate()),
(2, 200, 'DEF', newid(), getdate()),
(3, 300, 'KLM', newid(), getdate()),
(4, 400, 'XYZ', newid(), getdate());


select 
    [name] = o.[key],
    VALUE = CAST(o.[value] as NVARCHAR(MAX))
from
(
select (select d.* for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) as thejson
from @deleted as d
) as src
cross apply openjson(src.thejson) as o;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but I think this is what I have already; I have a single json value with all of the data, but I can't find a way to break it into individual records, so that each set of data is it's own row.  I think the script that I linked to has the same issue.